# How to define an abstract (opaque) interface for a polymorphic object type?

Tags: ocaml, reason, rescript

ReasonML

```
module type T = {
  type t('a); // Does not work
  type b; // Works
};

module A: T = {
  type t('a) = {.. b: bool} as 'a;
  type b = bool;
};
module B: T = {
  type t('a) = {.. c: int} as 'a;
  type b = int;
};
```

Ocaml

```
module type T  = sig
  type 'a t /* Doesn't work */
  type b /* Works */
end
module A : T = struct type 'a t = < b :bool  ;.. > as 'a
                      type b = bool end 
module B : T = struct type 'a t = < c :int  ;.. > as 'a
                      type b = int end
```

How can I define the module type A t('a) so that it is abstract but compatible with the open polymorphic object types in the implementations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types `<b : bool; .. >` and `<c : int; ..>` are not compatible much like `int` and `bool` are not compatible. In other words, if we will put [row polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092739/what-are-row-types-are-they-algebraic-data-types/48093540) aside, and focus on simple type constructors, then you're trying to define an interface that matches type `int` and `bool` and nothing else, aka [bounded polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification).

It is also important to understand that [subtyping is not inheritance](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/oreilly-book/html/book-ora144.html#toc212). In your case, you have two classes of objects, the `b`-class objects that have method `b`

```
class virtual b = object
  method virtual b : bool
end
```

and the `c`- class of objects that have method `c`,

```
class virtual c = object
  method virtual c : int
end
```

and we can define a class of objects `bc` that have both methods, naturally via inheritance,

```
class virtual bc = object
  inherit b
  inherit c
end
```

Now, let's cooks some objects to play with,

```
let b : b = object method b = true end
let c : c = object method c = 42 end
let bc : bc = object
  method b = false
  method c = 56
end
```

We can see that despite that `bc` class type is defined as inherited from b and c we can't coerce `b` to `c`,

```
# (b : b :> bc);;
Line 1, characters 0-13:
1 | (b : b :> bc);;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Type b = < b : bool > is not a subtype of bc = < b : bool; c : int > 
       The first object type has no method c
```

and this makes perfect sense since we're trying to downcast an object of the base class to an object of the derived class, which is an illegal operation. Therefore, when you have a hierarchy of class types ordered by inheritance, the base classes are super types and the derived classes are subtypes. E.g., if `v` inherits from `u` then `v` is a subtype of `u`,

```
v inherits-from u
-----------------
   u :> v
```

Once you get a clear understanding of this, you can design a proper interface.

Comment: I understand A.t and B.t are incompatible, but how can I define an abstract interface that is compatible? For example, bool and int are incompatible, but I can still define type b in the interface. If we remove module B entirely, the code still doesn't compile.

Comment: Given you initial design constraint, there is no such interface. That is what I and @octachron are trying to say. So you need to rethink why you ended up in incompatible interfaces or post another question that will describe your original problem. Given the way it is state the answer is simple - no, there is no such module type and should not be.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if it is really useful but you need to add the constraint explicitly in the module type:

```
module type TA  = sig
  type 'a t constraint 'a = < b:bool; .. >
end
module A : TA = struct
  type 'a t = < b :bool  ;.. > as 'a
end
```

Comment: How can TA also be compatible with module B? For example, I'd like to implement an interface (type class) to use with a Functor, and module A or B can be passed in.

Comment: You cannot. The constraints on the type parameter `'a`  in `A` and `B` are incompatible with each other.