# Why use objects instead of records in GADT?

Tags: ocaml, gadt

I'm looking at GADT definitions, and they use objects instead of records. I was wondering why, as it seems like objects are pretty much never used in general in OCaml. Is there a difference?

For example:

```ml
type (_, _, _) Basic.t +=
  | Field : ('field1, 'field2, < field1 : 'field1 ; field2 : 'field2 ; .. >) t
```

Comment: Objects are structural and subtype polymorphic, which means one object type can be compatible with another if it includes the same structural elements. Note the `..` at the end of the type here, which means it is "open" and will be compatible with types that have at least these fields. Beyond that I can only speculate.

Comment: @glennsl, OCaml doesn't have subtype polymorphism, only row polymorphism. That is why we need sometimes to explicitly upcast to the base type using `:>`.

Answer (score 0):

Objects offer a unique type system feature, called [row polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48115287/2625442). It is hard to tell without any more context why is row polymorphism required in this particular example, I can only tell that this constructor represents a family of row polymorphic types of objects that has at least two methods, `field1` and `field2` of type `'field1` and `'field2` correspondingly.